# SQL Finding the size of query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So basically I'm doing a SQL select query, but I want to know how much data I am pulling back (how many kilobytes), any way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Actually, "[Show Client Statistics](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/01/sql-server-sql-server-management-studio-and-client-statistics/)" within SSMS query Editor Window will return the resultset size, Bytes Received from Server, etc

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT <your query here>
INTO dbo.MyTempTable
FROM <query source>

exec sp_spaceused 'MyTempTable'

DROP TABLE MyTempTable
```

This wlil Return Rows, Reserved Space, Data space (in KB), Index space, and unused space for that table.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because with this approach you don't have to transmit all the data over a (perhaps slow) network.

Comment: Note that in the case of a temporary table, you must call the sp from the temp db as follows:  
  
```EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_spaceused N'#YourTempTable';```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the actual execution plan of the query in the Results window of SSMS, which will display an estimated row size for the results.  Multiply that by the number of rows to get your result.  Not sure how accurate the estimated row size is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_spaceused to get the size of a table.  But I am unaware of any way to get the size of a query (of course that means little).

One way to get a quick estimate of the size would be to save the data as a text file.  Obviously, there will be extra whitespace.  But it would give you a general idea on how large the query is.