# Way to know the amount of data generated by a given query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

Typically, it is possible to know how many lines a query returns by using COUNT(*).

In the same manner, is there any way know how many megabytes for example the output of a given query is ?

Something like

```
SELECT MEMORYUSE(*) FROM bla bla bla
```

**EDIT** : I like the *exec sp_spaceused ... * approach, as it can be scripted!

Comment: What database do you use? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: In that case, check my answer.

Comment: @hgulyan: Thanks a lot. I upboated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, there are a couple of options to give you more information about the executing / executed query that you can view / set using SSMS as well.  As shown below, the rowcount for the query is shown in the bottom right of SSMS by default.  Also, I've highlighted the advanced query options, which you can set globally as shown here.  Of course, you can also turn any of these options on for the particular statement or batch by including them in the query, i.e. 'set showplan_test on', etc..

[image: Output and Configuration options in SSMS]

Also you can turn on 'show client statistics' in SSMS as shown below (with sample output).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **SQL Server**, turn on **Client Statistics** and you 'll find *"Bytes sent from client"* and *"Bytes received from server"*

Here is related question

[SQL Finding the size of query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473023/sql-finding-the-size-of-query-result)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful:

[SQL Server Query Size of Results Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450248/sql-server-query-size-of-results-set)

I don't think there is anyway without creating a temp table for the results and checking the size.